# getTemplate() is not working $parents[1].getRegion Knockout js

Tags: magento, knockout.js, magento2, checkout

I am using magneto onestep checkout.
One extension which is custom shipping method. here the issue is custom shipping method is loading the shipping method but along with shipping method its provide one button on click it wil show the shop for the pickup.

Now, This extension is not working with onestep checkout.

```
<!-- ko foreach: $parents[1].getRegion('shipping-details') -->
     <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

here get template is not getting loaded, i tried many ways to load the getregion and Knockout debugger, its not showing my components to load the gettempalte file content.